# VBA Looping through 2 ranges and applying IF statement to values from both ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to excel VBA and I am trying to write a code that checks a couple of values and highlights the values that match the IF statements.

Within a table, I need to loop through all values in two different ranges, the values of one range being dates and the values of the other being several different strings, and highlight (orange) the rows that correspond to the following requirements: (1) 1st range value >= to today's date and (2) 2nd range value = "Sample Receipt". I also need to loop through all values of the ranges of dates and highlight (yellow) the rows that correspond to vale > today's date. All other rows of the table that do not correspond to those requirements then need to be highlighted a light blue color.

My first code (shown below) kind of worked, but it highlighted all values of the 2nd range that = "Sample Receipt".

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate

With ActiveSheet

 LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 For Each cell In Range("K3:K" & LastRow)
     If cell.Value >= Date Then
        cell.Range("A1:K1").Offset(0, -10).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
     ElseIf cell.Value >= Date - 7 Then
            For Each cell2 In Range("H3:H" & LastRow)
                If cell2.Value = "Sample Receipt" Then
                 cell2.Range("A1:K1").Offset(0, -7).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
                Else
                 cell2.Range("A1:K1").Offset(0, -7).Interior.Color = RGB(220, 230, 242)
                End If
            Next
     Else
        cell.Range("A1:K1").Offset(0, -10).Interior.Color = RGB(220, 230, 242)
     End If
 Next
End With
```

I cannot think of another way to set up the For loops to allow for what I need and I have looked around.

Comment: A picture of before and after would be helpful because while you say highlight rows, your code only highlights certain cells (so which is it?) And you can apply multiple criteria to an if statement with `and` if that's your intention (unclear to me).

Comment: That is some funky code - the For Each cell2 loop does not make sense to me. Are you sure you can't get what you want with conditional formatting?

Comment: If you want to look at the value in column H on the same row as `cell` then you can refer to that using `cell.Offset(0, -3)`

Comment: @findwindow I meant that I need to highlight the row within the table. I did not know how to apply multiple criteria to an IF statement within a loop using values from two different ranges.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I probably could have done it with conditional formatting, but I wanted to see if it was possible in VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub TT()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dt, txt
    Dim clr As Long

    Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    LastRow = sht.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In sht.Range("K3:K" & LastRow).Cells

        dt = cell.Value
        txt = cell.Offset(0, -3).Value

        'don't follow your original logic so
        '  this is just an example....
        If dt >= Date And txt = "Sample Receipt" Then
           clr = vbRed
        ElseIf dt >= Date - 7 Then
           clr = vbYellow
        Else
           clr = RGB(220, 230, 242) 'default color
        End If

        cell.EntireRow.Cells(1).Color = clr

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! I had to change a couple of things, but it works like a charm now. The logic makes a lot more sense :).